# Non-capturing lookbehind regex match is not working

Tags: regex

Problem statement is as follows.

my description is

abc abcxxyz 10xabc abcx10 abc10xabc abcx10xyz

want the regex which will match abc only if it is preceded by digit + x or succeeded by x + digit.

In above example it should match abc from abcx10 , 10xabc and abcx10xyz
but should not capture digits in those matches.
that means while replacing text it should replace only abcx or xabc.

Have tried `(((((?:\d+)))[Xx]))(abc)(\s|$|(([Xx](?=((\d).)+)))|[^a-zA-Z0-9])` but it is not excluding digits from capturing.

Thanks.

Comment: Have tried (((((?:\d+)))[Xx]))(abc)(\s|$|(([Xx](?=((\d).)+)))|[^a-zA-Z0-9]) but it is not excluding digits from capturing.

Comment: There is no lookbehind in your pattern. Start to remove all useless groups in your pattern to make it more clear and more easy to debug. What language do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
((?<=\d[Xx])abc)|(abc(?=[Xx]\d))
```

[Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/cD5hI6/1)

Notice that the lookbehind cannot have any quantifiers - it has to have known and defined length.

If you want to get abcx and xabc, there is slightly different version:

https://regex101.com/r/cD5hI6/2

Comment: If I understand well, x must be included in the match. Note that capture groups may not be necessary if the goal is to replace.

Comment: The OP hasn't said yet what flavor he's using.  Some *do* allow quantifiers in lookbehinds, and some don't support lookbehinds at all.

Comment: I know javascript doesn't, but I hope OP will tell if it is javascript.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. This is working perfectly fine in java but same regex I have to apply in javascript also. It is giving me SyntaxError: invalid regexp group error as ?<= is not supported in javascript. Is there any alternative available in javascript for this.